# Toolbar position

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I am developing a RCP4 application, where I used toolbar. In some system toolbar and part label are same alignment. But some system toolbar is coming another line of part tab. Why this kind of things are happening?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some pictures please.

Comment: If there isn't space for the tool bar on the same line at the part tab it is displayed on the next line.

Comment: @greg-449 I added the image for different screen. Please look at the image!

Comment: I find it suspicious that icons are significantly higher in the second case. Do they fit in tab bar?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is because the height of the icons in the tool bar are bigger than the calculated height of the part tab area. This causes `CTabFolder` to move them to the next line.

You can set the height of a `CTabFolder` in the CSS using `swt-tab-height`. For the part stack folder this may work:

```css
.MPartStack 
{
   swt-tab-height: 22px;
}
```